# How to access request.params.? in Cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In a cloud function, on Parse.com: I need to access parameters from a loop.
To be clear, the function receives the parameters: request.params.PT1, request.params.PT2, ….. request.params.PT9.

my loop inside the function goes like:

```
for (i=1; i<=9; ++i) {
    // Do something with request.params.PTi:
    What is the right syntax to access request.params.PTi here ?
}
```

I need a generic way to access the different parameters using the loop index i
like if I was using request.params.PT1, request.params.PT2, ….. request.params.PT9 one after the other.

The few things I could think of and tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; ++i) {
    var thisParam = request.params["PT" + i];

    //To break when PTi is undefined
    if(typeof thisParam === undefined) {
        break;
    }
}
```